# Find $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$.

Tags: calculus

> Find $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\ln(x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$.

Do I change the limits of integration and add the two here?

Comment: i got the answer "0" here

Comment: How do you do it?